# Ionic - build iOS package file for testing on device

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

Currently I am trying to build a new app with Ionic 3. I am looking for steps to build a file for installation, which has the same functionality with APK file for android devices. I don't know whether it should be an IPA file or other file types, as I have never used an iPhone or iPad myself before. Right now, I have a free developer account registered with Apple ID.

What I can find on the web seems only allow developers to build apps for testing on real devices which the developers have access to. To be more specific, I always see people say that users should plug in the device via USB and pick the target device in XCode under the "Scheme" drop down selector. I tried to follow the steps provided by others, but it always ended up with an error in XCode, either it is related to code signing error, or device not registered in my developer account.

What if I do not own any iOS devices? What I have is only a single MacBook for coding. I would like to prepare a file and send it to my friends, and let them install my app with that file on their iOS devices.

I am using XCode 9 and Ionic 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS you can no do what that, If you want to send your app to your friends for testing you have to build the app with `ionic cordova build ios` and then open the project in Xcode and build/upload your project to your Apple developer account.

After that, you have to use [Test Flight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) to share your app for testing.